# Riemmanian mean

Tags: geometry

I wonder if there is an explicit form to calculate the (weighted) average mean of points defined on a surface (Riemmanian manifold). The terms I found in multivariable case is the "Karcher mean", but the work is difficult to read and do not provide a computable formula.

Comment: imagine the punctured round sphere

Comment: I imagined. I Can't see your point.